# How to render html file as PDF using play framework 2.3x

Tags: java, playframework

I am using play 2.3.4 for an application. I have to render a html file to pdf.

Please help me with this.

Comment: You can find some good pointers in similar questions on SO, for example (this one)[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6118635/what-is-the-best-pdf-open-source-library-for-java].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a lot of libraries in the Java to transform HTML in to PDF. For example - [iText](http://hmkcode.com/itext-html-to-pdf-using-java/)

Java code would be like:

```
package com.hmkcode;
 
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;
import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.XMLWorkerHelper;
 
public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws DocumentException, IOException
    {
      // step 1
        Document document = new Document();
        // step 2
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("pdf.pdf"));
        // step 3
        document.open();
        // step 4
        XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml(writer, document,
                new FileInputStream("index.html")); 
        //step 5
         document.close();
 
        System.out.println( "PDF Created!" );
    }
}
```

The same for scala. You can use [sPDF](https://github.com/cloudify/sPDF) for example. The code would be like

```
val pdf = Pdf(PdfConfig.default)

val result = Future { pdf.run(new URL("http://www.google.com"), new File("google.pdf")) }
```